# Is it possible to randomly choose a player to be killer?

Tags: dead-by-daylight

When playing with friends, we'd prefer if one of us was randomly made a killer, rather than having to explicitly choose ourselves.  Is this possible?

Comment: An Out of game option that always worked for me and my friends is a [virtual dice roll](https://www.wizards.com/dnd/dice/dice.htm). Everyone roles the same die, and whoever gets the highest number is the killer.

Comment: @Malco But no one's supposed to know who the killer is. It's like a Murder Mystery game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the game does not provide such a feature yet. It is also unsure if it will provide such a feature in the near future.

Comment: Well that's unfortunate.  Why do so many asymmetric multiplayer devs not know their audience?

Comment: It's not a developer decision most of the time.

Comment: Well, I think it has a technical limit for now. The Killer is also treated as the host. In theory, it should be easy to change, but I don't know how they coded it. The request for making the killer a random choice exists for quite a while but hasn't been heard yet so far.

Comment: @Nelson: Of course it's a developer decision.  Who else could it be? The publisher is not going to care about this feature.